# Two different ways of substitution leads to two different results for $\int\frac{x\ln x^2+1}{x^2+1}dx$, how's that?

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

I was working on a solution for
$$\int\frac{x\ln (x^2+1)}{x^2+1}dx$$ and my approach was the following:

first substituting $u = x^2+1$, which means $du = 2x dx$, and therefore:
$$\int\frac{\ln u}{2u}du$$

and then substituting $v=\ln u$, which means $dv = \frac{1}{u} du$, and therefore:
$$\frac{1}{2}\int dv = \frac{v}{2} + c = \frac{\ln u}{2} +c = \frac{\ln (x^2+1)}{2}+c$$

However verifying this online from various sources, they indicate that the solution is in fact:
$$\int\frac{x\ln (x^2+1)}{x^2+1}dx = \frac{\ln(x^2+1)^2}{4}+c$$
because they substitute $u = \ln(x^2+1)$ which gives $du = \frac{2x}{x^2+1} dx$, which is clairly a shorter path.

But my question is, why does both of these substitution techniques not yield the same result? Where lies my error?

Comment: Your 3rd line should start: $\frac12\int v\,dv$

Comment: @mr_e_man right! I see my mistake now, thanks!

Comment: @Void You forgot $dx$ when you wrote $du = 2x$

Comment: And you forgot the $+c\,$ on the right.

Answer (score 6):

When you get$$\int\frac{\ln u}{2u}\,\mathrm du$$and you do $v=\ln u$ and $\mathrm dv=\frac1u\,\mathrm du$, what you should have obtained was$$\int\frac v2\,\mathrm dv=\frac{v^2}4+c=\frac{\ln^2u}4+c=\frac{\ln^2(x^2+1)}4+c,$$instead of $\frac12\int\,\mathrm dv$.

Comment: Great! So this means that both ways of substituting are actually valid? I wasn't just "lucky" this time?

Comment: @Void In fact you did exactly the same substitution as those other sources; you just did it in two steps. In a way it's their fault for unnecessarily absorbing an exponent into the logarithm's argument, made doubly confusing for a beginner by their still leaving a coefficient outside. I'm surprised they did that instead of, for example, $\ln\sqrt{x^2+1}+c$. My guess is they're in the habit of rewriting $\ln|y|$ as $\frac{1}{2}\ln y^2$ to avoid modulus signs, but since $x^2+1>0$ it's unnecessary.

Comment: The square $^2$ actually should be outside the logarithm.

Comment: I realize now that my syntax wasn't very obvious, but as @mr_e_man pointed out, the square is outside the logarithm like so $\ln^2(x^2+1)$ which is not the same as $\ln((x^2+1)^2)$. My error was merely forgetting to enter the substituted $v$ in the third equation.

Comment: But $\ln^2(x^2+1)$ is not the same as $\ln((x^2+1)^2)$

Comment: @HenryLee You are totally right. I don't know what went through my mind. My answer was edited.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int\frac{x\ln(x^2+1)}{x^2+1}dx$$
$$u=x^2+1$$
$$dx=\frac{du}{2x}$$
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\ln(u)}{u}du$$
$$v=\ln(u)$$
$$du=udv$$
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int vdv=\frac{v^2}{4}+C=\frac{\ln^2(u)}{4}+C=\frac{\ln^2(x^2+1)}{4}+C$$